# Jenkins pipeline not executing next stage after failure in one stage of running bash script

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am running a shell script inside a docker container via jenkins groovy pipeline script. The bash script sets some environment variables and then executes unit tests. The stdout of these unit test execution is dumped to a text file.
I later copy this text file outside of the container for usage.
Here is the shell script:

```
#/bin/bash
source /root/venv/bin/activate
export PYTHONPATH=/foo/bar
cd unit_tests
rm -f results.txt
python tests.py >> results.txt
```

My pipeline script is as follows:

```
        stage('Run Unit Tests') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    docker-compose -f ./dir1/docker-compose-test.yml up -d
                    docker cp /supporting_files/run_unit_tests.sh container_1:/foo/bar/
                    docker exec container_1 /bin/bash run_unit_tests.sh
                    docker cp container_1:/foo/bar/unit_tests/results.txt .
                '''
            }
        }
        stage('Reporting') {
            steps {
                //steps for reporting
            }
        }
```

The problem is whenever any test fails, the results.txt has the appropriate text about failures and their stack. But the pipeline stop executing saying

```
[Pipeline] }
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
```

Because of this I am not able to execute next steps of parsing the results.txt file and reporting the results.
How do I make the pipeline execute next stage ?

I tried some things like:
1. Using catchError:

```
stage('Run Unit Tests') {
    steps {
        catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
            sh '''
                //Running the commands above
            '''
        }
    }
}
```

2. Using try:

```
    try{
        stage('Run Unit Tests') {
            sh '''
                //Executing tests
            '''
        }
    } catch(e) {
        echo e.toString()  
    }
```

But both of them does not help.
Also the shell script simply dumps the stdout of running tests into a text file so I don't understand why an exit code 1 should be returned as the operation itself does not fail. I saw the text file later, it had the correct failures and error counts with stack.

Comment: Have you tried running this example without the typo in `docker cp continer_1`? The `continer_1` misses `a`.

Comment: Hi @SzymonStepniak, thanks for noticing, the actual container name is different and long, I just put 'container_1' here for simplicity purposes.